# Django modelform validation

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using django modelforms and formsets. But the problem I am facing is that when the form is not validated, instead of showing the erros on the html page it gives and error in the view.

View `

```
def create(request):         
    if request.method=="POST":                                                          
        foo= fooform(request.POST,prefix="fooform") 
        if foo.valid():
           #do stuff             
    else:
        foo= fooform(prefix="fooform")          
    return render(request,'property/create.html',{'foo':foo})
```

`

Problem:

When the form does not validate there is a obvious error in the view where in it unable to find the fooform. I want the html page to show the error-ed fields. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I think I have found the main issue. The issue is that the **modelform is not applying its form validations at the browser level**. Because of this the form is getting submitted even though it is not valid. As a result it is failing the validation and not finding the else part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using this pattern instead:

```
def create(request):         
    foo = fooform(request.POST or None, prefix='fooform')
    if foo.valid():
        #do stuff             

    return render(request,'property/create.html', {'foo': foo})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your las line is wrong:

It say:

```
return render(request,'property/create.html',{'foo':fooform})
```

And should be:

```
return render(request,'property/create.html',{'foo':foo})
```

If this is not the issue, please, post errors messages and form code.